# Looping over distinct cell ranges to write formulas in each using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have a large forecasting spreadsheet I work with and I'm trying to write formulas into distinct ranges of cells (that correspond to months).

```
Sub prediction()
Dim rng As Range, i As Range, colCount As Integer
Set rng = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("mySheet").Range("D20:G20, H20:K20, L20:O20, P20:T20, U20:X20, Y20:AB20, AC20:AG20, AH20:AK20, AL20:AP20, AQ20:AT20, AU20:AX20, AY20:BB20")
colCount = 3
For Each i In rng
    i.Formula = "=ROUNDUP(" & Sheets("Forecast").Cells(16, colCount).Address(True, True, xlA1, True) & "/" & Sheets("Forecast").Cells(5, colCount).Address(True, True, xlA1, True) & ",0)"
    colCount = colCount + 1
Next i
End Sub
```

Those ranges are next to each other in the worksheet, obviously, and what happens is that VBA is writing the formula sequentially. For example, in `D20:G20` I want `=ROUNDUP(FORECAST!$C$16/FORECAST!$C$5,0)`, but VBA is writing the next formula in `E20` as `=ROUNDUP(FORECAST!$D$16/FORECAST!$D$5,0)` and so on.

Now, I don't know if this is a problem with the way VBA handles ranges (I'm new to VBA) but the way I solved it was by specifically naming separate ranges and then writing the formula individually.

```
Set jan = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("mySheet").Range("D20:G20")
Set feb = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("mySheet").Range("H20:K20")
jan.Formula = "=ROUNDUP(" & Sheets("Forecast").Cells(16, 3).Address(True, True, xlA1, True) & "/" & Sheets("Forecast").Cells(5, 3).Address(True, True, xlA1, True) & ",0)"
feb.Formula = "=ROUNDUP(" & Sheets("Forecast").Cells(16, 4).Address(True, True, xlA1, True) & "/" & Sheets("Forecast").Cells(5, 4).Address(True, True, xlA1, True) & ",0)"
```

Etc etc. This doesn't seem elegant, let alone efficient.

Question: is the problem with how I'm naming the range, or with how I'm constructing my loop?

Thanks.

Comment: You need to use the `.Areas` property, so using your original code, your For Each line becomes `For Each i In rng.Areas` and then it will populate the formula as desired.

Comment: Without the `.Areas` it assumes you want `.Cells` so then it loops through each cell individually, instead of each defined cell grouping (which is termed an Area in VBA)

Comment: @tigeravatar post answer?

Comment: [Union](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/BetterUnion.aspx) may be useful as well

Comment: @tigeravatar yes that did it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this...
It utilizes an array to convert the range groups ("D20:G20" etc...) into array elements that can be evaluated individually when you loop through the array with `For i = lbound(array) to ubound(array)`...lbound stands for lower bound and ubound stands for upper bound).  then each array element is converted to a range by Set `rng = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("mySheet").Range(RngArr(i))`.  Finally you iterate through each cell in the range by `For Each r In rng`.  This allows the column integer to only increment fore each array element.

```
 Sub prediction()
    Dim RngStr As String, i As Integer, colCount As Integer
    Dim RngArr
    Dim rng As Range, r As Range
    RngArr = "D20:G20, H20:K20, L20:O20, P20:T20, U20:X20, Y20:AB20, AC20:AG20, AH20:AK20, AL20:AP20, AQ20:AT20, AU20:AX20, AY20:BB20"
    RngArr = Split(RngArr, ",")
    colCount = 3
    For i = LBound(RngArr) To UBound(RngArr)
        Set rng = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("mySheet").Range(RngArr(i))
        For Each r In rng
            r.Formula = "=ROUNDUP(" & Sheets("Forecast").Cells(16, colCount).Address(True, True, xlA1, True) & "/" & Sheets("Forecast").Cells(5, colCount).Address(True, True, xlA1, True) & ",0)"
        Next r
        colCount = colCount + 1
    Next i
    End Sub
```

Comment: The solution that @tigeravatar had in his answer worked for that first use case, but this will be more useful as what I'm doing gets more advanced and want to iterate through multiple worksheets.

Comment: great I'm glad it helped!